# PHP SESSION array vars to XML

Tags: php, xml, session

I have a bunch of SESSION variables that I am trying to export to an XML file. The customer details were fine, as they are not part of a foreach loop. However, my customer's orders are part of a foreach loop.

The SESSION variable $_SESSION['invoice'] is defined in the cart.php. Each individual value in the $_SESSION['invoice'] array needs to be retrieved and placed into XML.

e.g.

```
<title1>comic title1</title1><qty1>10</qty1><price1>$2.50</price1><cost1>$25.00</cost1><title2>comic title2</title2><qty2>5</qty2><price2>$2.00</price2><cost2>$10.00</cost2>
```

cart.php code:

```
$_SESSION['invoice'][$comic_id]=$name . " " . $qty . " $" . $price . " $" . $cost;
```

xml.php code:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
     session_start();
}
foreach ($_SESSION['invoice'] as $value);

$test_array = array (
  $_SESSION['firstname'] => 'firstname',
  $_SESSION['lastname'] => 'lastname',
  $_SESSION['email'] => 'email',
  $_SESSION['addressline1'] => 'addressline1',
  $_SESSION['towncity'] => 'towncity',
  $_SESSION['postcode'] => 'postcode',
  'order' => array (
  $_SESSION['total'] => 'total',
  $_SESSION['invoice']  => 'order',
  ),
);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<customer/>');
array_walk_recursive($test_array, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
print $xml->asXML();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $_SESSION['invoice'][$comic_id]=$name . " " . $qty . " $" . $price . " $" . $cost;
```

With this code you concatinate string. Try to debug the created value like:

```
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($_SESSION['invoice'][$comic_id], 1).'</pre>';
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($_SESSION['invoice'], 1).'</pre>';
```

You have to create this something like:

```
    $_SESSION['invoice'][$comic_id]['firstname'] = 'Firstname';
    $_SESSION['invoice'][$comic_id]['price'] = $myPrice';
    // and so on...
```

But one note. It is not recommended IMHO to you the session for such an invoice handling!

Comment: This way wont work, as all the concatenated values/rows wont be pulled back from the array.

Answer (score 0):

$order = json_encode($_SESSION['invoice']);